# How to add top and bottom margins to leaflet popup with scroll

Tags: leaflet, popup, css

I've been customizing Leaflet in order to let popup display more content by adding scrolling to them. Everything works fine except my content touches top and bottom of the popup window.

How can I add a margin at top and bottom ?

Here's my custom CSS:

```
.custom-popup, .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
    background:#e7e7e7;
    color:#504e4e;
    font-family: 'Molengo', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    height : 10 px ;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    }

.leaflet-popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    }

.custom-popup, .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    }

.leaflet-popup-content { 
     min-width: 100 px !important;
    }
```

And here's a capture of what I have and what I would like to get: 
[image]

Scrollbar is on the right side of the popup :
[image]

EDIT : Blur effect I try to obtain (red arrows)
[image]

Comment: Where is the vertical scroll bar in the 'I want to have' picture?

Comment: I did put an screen cap to show scrollbar. It's on the mac so it disappears fast when inactive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't get your strategy that both `custom-popup` and `leaflet-popup-content-wrapper` style classes have `overflow: auto` property to work properly.

I moved `overflow: auto` property to `leaflet-popup-content` style class which is applied only to inner content of popup.

Here is working solution that has been tested on IE11 and latest versions of Firefox and Chrome:

```
.custom-popup {
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #504e4e;
    font-family: 'Molengo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 10px;
    height: 10 px ;
    max-height: 300px;
    }

.custom-popup, .leaflet-popup-tip {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    }

.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
   background: #e7e7e7;
   border-radius: 2px;
   }

.leaflet-popup {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    }

.leaflet-popup-content {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    min-width: 100 px !important;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Popup has to be defined with `className: 'custom-popup'` property:

```
var myPopup = L.popup({className: 'custom-popup'}).setContent('....');
```

Below are examples of popup with overflow and scroll bar and without overflow:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello TomazicM, Thanks you very much for your help ! You right about Overflow position. I didn't manage to get it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hi TomazicM Last question : I found the top and bottom a bit harsh and would like to add blur to show content overflow to user and soften a bit the design. Have you an idea on how to add this (I added an image in the original post). Thanks !

Comment: If you want blurr to appear only when there is overflow, I don't think this is achievable with CSS only. It would require some Java Script code. Since this is pure HTML question, you should post it to https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Actually, blur can be there even when there is no overflow

Comment: thanks @TomazicM. Works nicely. I was using a Bootstrap-4 scrollable table with sticky header, but this is simpler/cleaner.

`
// Table style with sticky header - in case


var popUpText = Object.entries(properties).map(function ([key, val]) {
            return ('<tr><td class="col-md-6">' + `${key}` + '</td><td>' + `${val}` + '</td></tr>')}).join('')


popUpText = '<div class="popup-table row">' + '<table class="border">' 
+ '<thead><th class="col-md-6">Key</th><th class="col-md-6">Value</th></thead>' 
+  '<tbody>' + popUpText + '</tbody>' + '</table>' + '</div>'
`