# Scrollbar On Leaflet Popup

Tags: leaflet

Very new to Leaflet, but learning fast. In the following code example, where/how would I define maxHeight to get the scrollbar in popup for data?

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [40.75, -74.15],
    zoom: 13
});

var osmAttrib = 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib
}).addTo(map);

var cities = new L.LayerGroup([
    L.marker([40.72801, -74.07772]).bindPopup('Jersey City')
]);
cities.addTo(map);

L.imageOverlay(
    'http://research.ccountync.com/maps/images/yellow.png',
    [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]], {
    opacity: 1
}).addTo(map).bindPopup("This is a yellow box");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add top and bottom margins to leaflet popup with scroll](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327097/how-to-add-top-and-bottom-margins-to-leaflet-popup-with-scroll)

Comment: I used that custom CSS locally and never got the scrollbar.

Comment: Edit you question with what you have tried and does not work for you.